# CSS Half Moon Background Image Mask

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have really spent quite come time trying to sort this out but I just can't get it to work. I built a base demo here for anyone to use.

What I want to happen is that the image should display as a half moon over the gray background. And this half moon should scale according to the height of the FlexContainer. Check my two images of how the final product should look. Don't worry about getting the circle radius correct.

The green background in the code is just to see the size of the svg, you can remove it. The edge of the circle should always be in the center of the screen (my examples are NOT centered correctly)

Before flex wrap:
[image]

After flex wrap:
[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.FlexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.FlexItem {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg style="background-color:green" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <clipPath id="circleView">
            <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200"/>
        </clipPath>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://imgur.com/KqppSIN.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"/>
    </svg> 
    <div class="FlexContainer">
        <div class="FlexItem"></div>
        <div class="FlexItem"></div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to another idea you can use `radial-gradient`  for this which is easier than svg *(of course the rendrering of svg is slightly better)*

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.FlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at right, transparent 50%, gray 50.5%), url("https://imgur.com/KqppSIN.jpg") center/cover;
}

.FlexItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem"></div>
  <div class="FlexItem"></div>
</div>
```

Here is another idea with the CSS clip-path that will allow you to have same result as svg but you need to pay attention to [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.FlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.FlexContainer:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://imgur.com/KqppSIN.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(70.0% at 100% 50%);
clip-path: circle(70.0% at 100% 50%);
}
.FlexItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem"></div>
  <div class="FlexItem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't mind using it, it is actually A LOT easier than the svg method. The only slight problem is that the border gets very blurry on a large window. Any idea how to remove that effect? Without the blurry this will be 100% correct!

Comment: @Frank adjust the % values ... make the second one 50% instead of 51% ... play with them until you get want you want ;)

Comment: Well I played around with them but they still seem quite blurry hey, even on 0 or 50%. When I mean quite blurry I mean they are not exactly a solid line. A few pixels are blurry (a small visible amount) and that doesn't look too nice you know. Not as clear as an svg

Comment: @Frank well for sure it's not like SVG :) an idea is to try to find the adequat values and you may also consider media query to change the value for different size ... ti's easier than SVG but svg remain more precise for such thing ;)

Comment: Well your answer works for sure, thank you for that, but you don't by any chance know how to fix it in svg then? XD

Comment: @Frank yes am thinking about it also ;) will update if i find an idea :)

Comment: Thank you! Would appreciate it :)

Comment: @Frank updated ;) i added a new way with the CSS clip-path and you won't have blur effect with it

Comment: There we go my friend! It was an honor :)